# MAX to SVF causes aesthetic problems

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

what's causing the textured material to lose its quality/resolution when translated from MAX to SVF?

example / illustration in the image below:

[image]

**EDIT/UPDATE Model Translation Status:**

```
{
    "type": "manifest",
    "hasThumbnail": "true",
    "status": "success",
    "progress": "complete",
    "region": "US",
    "urn": "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6am1kaDRvMDR3a24ydmpjOGF2andhMjVrbXJ5Z2dpdmQyMDE5MDIyNnQxNDU1NTU2Nzh6L01vZGVsbFRleHQuemlw",
    "version": "1.0",
    "derivatives": [
        {
            "name": "Final-Bake.max",
            "hasThumbnail": "true",
            "status": "success",
            "progress": "complete",
            "outputType": "svf",
            "children": [
                {
                    "guid": "15e32675-3874-4586-b00e-f6b1ec268dbf",
                    "type": "geometry",
                    "role": "3d",
                    "name": "3d Scene",
                    "status": "success",
                    "progress": "complete",
                    "hasThumbnail": "true",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "guid": "d43b2b8f-9245-431f-9745-6cfa67d03283",
                            "type": "resource",
                            "urn": "urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6am1kaDRvMDR3a24ydmpjOGF2andhMjVrbXJ5Z2dpdmQyMDE5MDIyNnQxNDU1NTU2Nzh6L01vZGVsbFRleHQuemlw/output/Final-Bake.svf",
                            "role": "graphics",
                            "mime": "application/autodesk-svf"
                        },
                        {
                            "guid": "79537c8e-0cd4-4eae-97e9-8457e313248c",
                            "type": "resource",
                            "urn": "urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6am1kaDRvMDR3a24ydmpjOGF2andhMjVrbXJ5Z2dpdmQyMDE5MDIyNnQxNDU1NTU2Nzh6L01vZGVsbFRleHQuemlw/output/Final-Bake.svf.png01_thumb_400x400.png",
                            "resolution": [
                                400,
                                400
                            ],
                            "mime": "image/png",
                            "role": "thumbnail"
                        },
                        {
                            "guid": "225043e7-c880-4dbe-9d32-f3dbc3071615",
                            "type": "resource",
                            "urn": "urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6am1kaDRvMDR3a24ydmpjOGF2andhMjVrbXJ5Z2dpdmQyMDE5MDIyNnQxNDU1NTU2Nzh6L01vZGVsbFRleHQuemlw/output/Final-Bake.svf.png01_thumb_200x200.png",
                            "resolution": [
                                200,
                                200
                            ],
                            "mime": "image/png",
                            "role": "thumbnail"
                        },
                        {
                            "guid": "5a7fc6b8-f8b9-4228-8750-992e3462fbc2",
                            "type": "resource",
                            "urn": "urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6am1kaDRvMDR3a24ydmpjOGF2andhMjVrbXJ5Z2dpdmQyMDE5MDIyNnQxNDU1NTU2Nzh6L01vZGVsbFRleHQuemlw/output/Final-Bake.svf.png01_thumb_100x100.png",
                            "resolution": [
                                100,
                                100
                            ],
                            "mime": "image/png",
                            "role": "thumbnail"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "guid": "10ca8b71-543a-429e-a36c-66a43278cf5d",
                    "type": "resource",
                    "urn": "urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6am1kaDRvMDR3a24ydmpjOGF2andhMjVrbXJ5Z2dpdmQyMDE5MDIyNnQxNDU1NTU2Nzh6L01vZGVsbFRleHQuemlw/output/properties.db",
                    "role": "Autodesk.CloudPlatform.PropertyDatabase",
                    "mime": "application/autodesk-db",
                    "status": "success"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how you do your conversion from MAX to SVF, your texture might get resized to make them smaller and faster to load.

If you export your 3ds Max file to SVF using the shared view feature, the "Optimize scene data" option may cause your large textures to be resized.

By default the exporter inside of max will not resize the texture.  However, when you are using the "shared view" feature, 3ds Max will save your last used settings inside an ini file "SvfExporter.ini". To turn off texture resizing you can go inside this ini file and change the "OptimizeMaps" value to 0.

By default this ini file will be located inside your user appData folder and will only be present if you used the "shared view" feature.
Ex:C:\Users\myUserName\AppData\Local\Autodesk\3dsMax\2020 - 64bit\ENU\en-US\plugcfg\SvfExporter.ini

If you simply uploaded your file to Autodesk cloud storage and a preview have been generated automatically for you or if you used the Autodesk Forge Model derivative API, then your texture should not get resized.

Update (2021-01-22): New development have been done since my original answer to better support PBR and Physical material conversion to SVF in the later versions of 3ds Max.  The texture should not be resized anymore (unless the "Optimize scene data" is selected in the shared view feature) and you should get significantly better looking result when using physical and/or PBR materials.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. It is Highly appreciated.
However, I am not quite sure if I know how to proceed. Currently we save our model as a MAX file and zip it together with all of its related textures. Then we do a ZIP to SVF translation using this Postman Collection: https://github.com/yiskang/forge.api.postman

Where in our workflow would we be able to modify the .ini?

Comment: Interesting I would have expected your texture to not get resized by the Model derivative API.  Can you track down your texture in the output of the SVF translation.  Validate that the resulting texture has the same resolution as the original one.

Comment: Thanks, I have added the results of the SVF translation in the original question above. Kindly take a look. Are those values (400x400, 200x200, 100x100) referring to the textures? If so, that's a huge resolution crop happening

Comment: The images you are talking about are thumbnail.  However, I did inspect the texture I first tough were not resized inside a web browser developer tools and realized they were resized to 1024x1024.

Comment: Seems indeed like all of the texture I'm referring to are being resized as well. Any tricks that you know of that would help us prevent the resizing?

Comment: Not that I know of today, I tried a couple of things unsuccessfully.  I will keep looking around and keep you posted if I find anything.

Comment: I have confirmed that sadly there is no way to control the resize behavior in the derivative service today.